# Laravel/Entrust - Get Roles For Permission

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get the permissions for a role with Laravel and Entrust. It uses a pivot table called `permission_role` that has the `role_id` and `permission_id` stored in it.

What I'm trying to do is get the role with it's ID and then get the permissions associated with that role. I think I may be over complicating it, but since I have had zero luck on it I was hoping someone could help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
// Hope you have something like this:
class Role extends EntrustRole {}
```

Then get all permissions from the role whose `id` is `1`:

```
$role = Role::with('perms')->find(1); // Assumed 1 is role id
dd($role->perms); // all permissions in the role
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I had my code a bit backwards.... I tried Role::find($id)->with('perms'); the result is perms becomes an undefined variable.